# Logical Address and Phyiscal Address with respect to Socket Programming

Tags: unix, networking, operating-system

Can anyone help me with How does Logical Address and Physical Address model work(From networking/ Socket point of view)? Why there is need to have two separate types of addresses?

Comment: You need to read a good book on Operating Systems.

Comment: actually on networking..

Answer (score 0):

Different networks use different physical addresses, for example the IEEE 802 MAC address uses a 48 bit address.

To connect different networks and still be able to address undividual machines they had to overcome the problem of these different schemas, so they created IP (IPv4 and later IPv6) addresses.

So when you send an IP packet from a machine to another it can travel through various networks, each network sending packets with its own addressing schema.

Comment: Does that mean, 
1) Logical Address is to support different physical address families 
2) First cast physical address to logical address and send it to the kernel. 
    Based on first two fields of logical address, kernel will determine the physical address family and will cast back logical address to physical address.

Comment: 1) something like that... 2) a) no cast, everything is done at kernel level. b) first two fields?? I have no idea what you mean... c) kernel determines physical interface based on routing table (unless you explicitly selected an interface (eg: for multicast)),  then for that interface it'll known address family and again, based on the routing table and arp requests it will determine the target physical address. logical address is sent in the packet so next machine will again make its decisions based on that...

Comment: So is it like, when system 1 wants to send a packet to system 2, kernel of system 1 will determine system2's physical address. Convert that to logical address based on protocol and address family and send it along with packet 2. On reception of packet, system 2 kernel will make logical to physical conversion again.
is that right?

Comment: @user1368949, first you need to distinguish between machines on the same network versus different network.  If it's on a different network, system 1 won't know the physical address of system 2.

Comment: So the thing i mentioned will work for if systems are on the same machine right?
how to handle case with machines of different n/w?

Comment: the routing table will give you the next machine in the chain. you're talking a lot of nonsense, you *really* should read a book.